# Date format not changed in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not able to change the date format in excel. I know this is very basic but somehow it's not working.

Following are the dates:

```
    04/30/1980
07/22/1991
01/01/2018
03/22/1979
02/22/1989
04/28/1987
08/19/1974
05/07/1971
12/14/1991
01/01/1988
03/09/1985
05/11/1992
05/23/1989
```

I want to convert these into something like 14-March-2012 format.

I changed the date format but it has zero effect. Please let me know where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: do you have a csv or an xls*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Format the column as General if it isn't then run Text-to-Columns, Fixed width, Next, Date - MDY then format the column as dd-mmmm-yyyy.

[image]